# Pass environment variables in Step functions

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-step-functions

I would like to pass environment variable(like passing prod or dev) in step functions so that pyspark program can get it by using os.getenv().There are many programs using same environment variables so passing them as arguments to the programs will take some time.Tried below code

```
[   
  {
   "Classification": "yarn-env",
   "Properties": {},
   "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
             "VARIABLE_NAME": VARIABLE_VALUE,
         }
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

but it didn't work.Seems this code will work for setting yarn configurations.

Comment: Step Functions itself does no processing, it only is an orchestration tool.  What do you mean by "programs" - lambdas? using the SDK in the defintion (ie: putting an item into an s3 bucket or something else?)  ec2 instances running some kind of app as a server based thing? How you do it will be different for each, but ultimately the SF cannot access some form of env file when its running, it will either need to be told the variables in its starting payload and pass them into the resources its calling, or the resources themselves will need it defined upon their creation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Apologize for the bad the explanation.Is there any option in step functions,where variables can be exported,just like spark configurations are exported in classification

Comment: You can use parameters on a task definition to send various information into a given task (such as adding it to the event being passed to a Lambda) but they either need to be "hardcoded" into the definition or they need to be determined by choice states from data in the event that is produced either entering the SF for the first time or from a previous Task.

Comment: I  have successfully passed parameter to task, but this particular scenario i have to use environment variables. I was not able to find any example of how i can use environment variables in step functions

Comment: because there is not one. Stepfunctions cannot access any sort of environment. An individual Lambda would be able too, but step functions themselves, and the definitions that are used to create them, do not have access to an "environment" to pull variable values from.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the SAM template.yaml as so

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        variable_name: variable_value
```

From your functions code you should then be able to retrieve this environment variable, for example in python with `os.getenv("variable_name")`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

If environment variables should only be available for a specific function similarly you could configure environment variables at the function resource level, see https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object